# How to loop an argument value in bash

Tags: bash

I want to loop over the value of an input argument, something like that

```
for i in {0..$1} do
  echo $i
done
```

If i call my script: ./my.sh 2

I want

```
0
1
```

But i get

```
{0..2}
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<=$1; ++i))`

Comment: Note that the accepted answer on the linked duplicate is *not* actually the best way to do it; I'll have to look for a better dup.

Comment: @chepner: The second answer is correct though

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

last=$(("$1"-1))
for i in $(seq 0 "$last");
    do echo "$i";
done
```